# Translate standardButton in QDialogButtonBox

Tags: internationalization, pyqt, translation

i am using *pyqt* and *designer*. i have translated all the strings in my app with self.tr() + pylupdate4 and lrelease

here is the snippet of code in my main():

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setApplicationName('Mental Calculation')

# initialize locale and load translation files if available
locale = QtCore.QLocale()
LOCALENAME = str(locale.system().name())
translator = QtCore.QTranslator()
translator.load("mentalcalculation_%s" % LOCALENAME)
app.installTranslator(translator)
```

I use a *QDialogButtonBox* in a *QDialog* with a *QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel* and a *QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok*

and the strings in these buttons are not translated. because *pylupdate4* does pick any string for them.

Have I missed a configuration step in my app so that they are translated ? 
I don't understand how the string for standard buttons of *QDialogButtonBox* are supposed to be translated and can't found doc about that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the method below to set the buttons' text:

```
buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok)->setText(tr("Ok"));
buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Cancel)->setText(tr("Cancel"));
```

then lupdate .ts file, open it with linguist and you'll find the strings.

Comment: Note that you may also need to include the QPushButton header:
 [#include <QPushButton>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290792/how-to-change-the-caption-of-a-button-in-a-qdialogbuttonbox)

Answer (score 5):

In order to load the native translations from QT in a portable way, you could use the following function call:

```
translator.load("qt_" + QLocale::system().name(),QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
```

The two (or more) translators as explained before, is the standard way if you would like to avoid the workaround.

Answer (score 4):

you should install 2 different translators:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

translator_my = QtCore.QTranslator()
translator_my.load('i18n/i18n_' + QtCore.QLocale.system().name() + '.qm')
#translator_my.load('i18n/i18n_ru_Ru.qm')
app.installTranslator(translator_my)

translator_qt = QtCore.QTranslator()
translator_qt.load('i18n/qt_' + QtCore.QLocale.system().name()[:2] + '.qm') 
#translator_qt.load('i18n/qt_ru.qm')
app.installTranslator(translator_qt)

myApp = MyMainWindow()
myApp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

where i18n/i18n_ru_Ru.qm is the path to your i18n file and qt_ru.qm was copied from usr/share/qt4/translations (in my case).

Answer (score 2):

I finally found what to do:
from http://qt.nokia.com/developer/faqs/faq.2008-05-06.6265952148 and http://qt.nokia.com/developer/faqs/705

so I just need to copy, for example french, the qt_fr.qm I found in **QTDIR/translations** (here /usr/share/qt/translations) into the directory of my application and add

```
translator.load("qt_%s" % LOCALENAME)
```

or even copy all the qt_*.qm file from **QTDIR/translations** to really support the maximum of locales.

**NO THIS IS NOT WORKING**. Only one of the 2 files is loading. so i can't have either my string translated or the QDailogButtonBox.

damn. this thing is getting in my nervS.

Comment: so i manually merge part of qt_fr.ts file into my ts file. sigh...

how this is possible ? noone use this or what ? at least in Qt.

Comment: after filling a bug report for this http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-8798 , i finally got it working the way it should:
"a QTranslator is a representation of exactly one TS file. you need to install multiple translators into the QApplication object. the FAQ entry is just wrong and will be fixed."

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qtranslator.html#details), you must create the translator object before the application widgets.  I can't be certain that is your problem since you omitted the code where your widgets are created, but make sure you ensure you are not creating them before the translator.

Answer (score -1):

yes. just below the snippet I gave, I create my main dialog.

The problem is Qtranslator could not translate those QDialogButtonBox button because there is no string to translate. so it must be qt that does that job internally. or with some mechanism I am not aware of.

here is another snippet of code generated by pyuic4

```
self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox, 8, 0, 1, 1)
```

How QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel string could be translated when there is no string in the code ???

Is it because I do not create a mainwindow and only use QDialog ??

I can't comment on swanson answer !

Comment: Ah it looks like you could possibly solve the problem by adding you own Cancel and Ok buttons instead of using `setStandardButtons()`

Comment: yes. I resist to use that work-around. because those buttons are swapped places when the platform changes. but it seems it is my only option.