# How to change the caption of a button in a QDialogButtonBox?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I have added a `QDialogButtonBox` button with the default *Cancel* and *OK* buttons.

Is there a way to change the **caption** of these buttons? For example, *OK* should become *Run*.

Comment: The stock buttons have translated captions and fixed meanings. You should never change their caption. Instead, add a custom (non-standard) button to the buttonbox.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You will have to do some coding in your **cpp** file:

```
ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok)->setText("Run");
ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Cancel)->setText("Exit");
```

Note that you may also need to include the **QPushButton** header:

```
#include <QPushButton>
```

#### Update:

Did not notice the **pyqt** tag. I'm not familiar with Python (and PyQt in particular), but I think this should do the job:

```
self.ui.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).setText("Run")
self.ui.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel).setText("Cancel")
```

Also, as pointed out by @[Kuba Ober](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329652), changing the text of standard buttons is not the best approach. The most **correct way** is to add custom buttons with an appropriate role.

```
self.ui.buttonBox.addButton("Run", QDialogButtonBox.ActionRole)
```

Comment: So using Qt Designer it is not possible to do this modification.. just by adding the code in the `.py`

Comment: @matteo I'm afraid it's not possible to do this via Qt Designer. All in all, writing the custom code is not that hard.

Comment: @kefir500, yeah that's sound pretty easy.. however I'm a bit surprised that a simple task like this has not been integrated in Qt.. Anyway.. thanks!

Comment: @kefir500 the `.setText` option is nolong working in PyQt5. It throwsback a exec_() == false or self.reject() resulting in -> exit app.

Comment: @ZF007. The `setText` method works perfectly fine in PyQt5 - there must be other problems with your code.

Comment: @ekhumoro .. yup...import QDialogButtonbox or `QDialogButtonBox`.. almost Shakespear!

Comment: had to remove `.ui` from the lines to work. `self.buttonBox.button(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok).setText("Fine!")`

Comment: Once I add the new button with `self.buttonBox.addButton("Run", QDialogButtonBox.ActionRole)` how do I remove the "OK" button?

Comment: Sorry, I answered my own comment: In the UI built by QtDesigner I found `self.buttonBox_calculate.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Close|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)` Just before adding the "Run" button, I added this line to my code `self.buttonBox_calculate.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Close)` It removes the "OK" button.